# Sorcery external: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, attr-accessible, sorcery

Tune gem Sorcery through article: github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/External.

I have done so, the user after login can create a recording and attach it to an image that is downloaded to the S3 from Amazon AWS. 
But after setting up I can log in, but I can not upload the image. In terminal writes an error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Card: review_date, original_text, translated_text, picture
```

Screenshot: http://monosnap.com/image/OyzrIct0G3uchY3XIUwyJEXxwUrcGU

In the settings of the controller's I use strong_parameters:

```
private
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:review_date, :original_text, :translated_text, :user_id, :picture, :remove_picture)
end
```

Help me! 
How to use strong_parameters the code?

P.S. Sure, I have written and the controller: https://gist.github.com/windsochi/86ab6f541445896e65f0.
I can not figure out how to get rid attr_accessible of and add strong_parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 4, make sure you use the `card_params` in your `new` and `create` actions:

```
def new
  @card = Card.new(card_params)
end

def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)
end

private
  def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:review_date, :original_text, :translated_text, :user_id, :picture, :remove_picture)
  end
```

If you are in rails 3, take a look at https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters